# Angular2 and simpleheat plugin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get work this NPM plugin (http://mourner.github.io/simpleheat/) with my angular2 app. It still doesn't work, but I think that everything is right but heatmap is not rendering.

My full repository with problem is there: https://github.com/b4rtt/nebula

heatmap.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { simpleheat } from 'simpleheat';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heatmap',
  templateUrl: './heatmap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heatmap.component.css']
})
export class HeatmapComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("myCanvas") myCanvas: ElementRef;
  context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let canvas = this.myCanvas.nativeElement;
    var data = [[38, 20, 1], [38, 690, 1], [48, 30, 1]];

    this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var ctx = this.context;

    //test draw
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);


    //doesn't work ?? Why?
    var heat = simpleheat(ctx);
    heat.data(data);
    heat.draw(100);
  }
}
```

heatmap.component.html

```
<canvas #myCanvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Anyone could help me what is wrong there?

Thank you

Comment: What is it that does not work?

Comment: @bugs heatmap is not rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of errors in your code;

1. You cannot import libraries that don't have type definitions so what you need to do is add the library to the .angular-cli.json file and declare the variable inside the component (or globally)
2. You were using ngAfterViewInit, but not implementing it
3. Simpleheat expects an id of the canvas element or a reference to it
4. The default route is not resolving to anything, which shows a blank page

After fixing all the above, the heapmap is showed.

[image]